# Neville's algorithm in C

Tags: c, numerical-analysis

I'm trying to implement [Neville's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm).

I have 32 points representing the sin(x) function:

```
int N=32,Nx=10000;
step = 1.0 / (N-1);
for (ii = 0; ii < N; ii++){ 
    px[ii] = ii*step*PI;
    py[ii] = sin(px[ii]);}
```

I have a input vector for evaluating the polynomial:

```
for (ii = 0; ii < Nx; ii++)
   x[ii] = 2.0 * rand() / (double) RAND_MAX; // 0 < x[ii] <= 2
```

This is my Neville's block:

```
double y[Nx];
for (kk=0;kk<Nx;kk++){// for each x[]'s element
    for (jj=1;jj<N-1;jj++){
        for (ii=0;ii<N-1-jj;ii++)
           s[ii]=(((px[jj]-x[kk])*py[ii])+((x[kk]-px[ii])*py[ii]))/(px[jj]-px[ii]);
    }
y[kk]=s[0];//insert in the output array the value just calculated
}
```

The problem is `s[ii]`, I'm not sure this count is correct.

Comment: Take a look at an algorithm [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=zXnSxY9G2JgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA123#v=onepage&q&f=false). See if you can implement it using 2D matrices.

Comment: Could you post your code as an [MWE](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html)? That way we can compile and test it. You can identify your code blocks with comments (as you should).

Comment: the code is here! https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12052224/int_res.c

Comment: A problem in the formula is that in the line `t3=(px[jj]-px[ii]);`, when `ii` is the same value as `jj`, `t3` is `0`, and the next line `s[ii]=(t1+t2)/t3;` divides by `0`, resulting in `nan`.

Comment: Yes, i have found the same problem. i'm working to resolve it but i have no ideas

Answer (score 2):

For Neville's method, you need to choose an x value to approximate `f(x)`, which is different from the values of the x array. I'm not sure which x value you were using, but from what I see, maybe you were trying to use all of the values from your `x[]` array.

I'm not sure if your implementation requires a 1D output array, but here's an example implementation using [this algorithm](http://books.google.com/books?id=zXnSxY9G2JgC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA123#v=onepage&q&f=false) with a 2D output array.

The example uses problem `1. a.` from the same page:

```
int i, j;
int n = 4;
double X; //X will be used to approximate f(X).
double x[n]; //The x values.
double y[n]; //The y or f(x) values.
double Q[n][n]; //The output table.

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        Q[i][j] = 0.0; //Initializing the Q matrix to 0.

//Hardcoding the x and y values from problem 1. a.
x[0] = 8.1;
x[1] = 8.3;
x[2] = 8.6;
x[3] = 8.7;
y[0] = 16.94410;
y[1] = 17.56492;
y[2] = 18.50515;
y[3] = 18.82091;

X = 8.4; //Want to approximate f(X), or f(8.4).

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    Q[i][0] = y[i]; //Setting the first column of Q to y[0] through y[3].

//Neville's method.
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        Q[i][j] = ((X - x[i - j])*(Q[i][j - 1]) 
                        - (X - x[i])*(Q[i - 1][j - 1]))/(x[i] - x[i - j]);
    }
}

printf("Resultant Q matrix:\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%9f ", Q[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The answer, `f(8.4)`, is the bottom rightmost number from the table, `17.877143`. It's plausible because `f(8.3) = 17.56492` and `f(8.6) = 18.50515`, and `17.877143` is between those two values.

Comment: thanks, I found many implementations using matrix, but i must use arrays.. in my algorithm i'm trying to calculate neville's polynomium for each value in the x[] array. In my opinion my problem isnt in the x[] array but is in the s[ii] formula

Comment: @user1066183 By matrix do you mean a 2D array? I was using array and matrix interchangeably. Does your implementation require that `s[ii]` be a one-dimensional array?

Comment: yes my implementation require that s[ii] be a one-dimension array.